# Syntax error or access violation issue in laravel create new table migration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have following create table migration in my laravel app

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateSchedulesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('schedules', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('department_id')->nullable()->after('id');
            $table->foreign('department_id')->references('id')->on('departments');
            $table->string('schedule_name');
            $table->date('schedule_start_date');
            $table->date('schedule_end_date');
            $table->date('schedule_actual_end_date');
            $table->time('schedule_travel_time');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('schedules');
    }
}
```

but when I try to run this migration I'm getting an error saying,

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'after `id`,
> `schedule_name` varchar(255) not null, `schedule_start_date` date...'
> at line 1 (SQL: create table `schedules` (`id` bigint unsigned not
> null auto_increment primary key, `department_id` bigint unsigned null
> after `id`, `schedule_name` varchar(255) not null,
> `schedule_start_date` date not null, `schedule_end_date` date not
> null, `schedule_actual_end_date` date not null, `schedule_travel_time`
> time not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp
> null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

I'm struggling to find where the issue is since I could not spot any syntax error here..

Comment: can u share the departments table migration too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove after code from function up. Because you are creating migration not updating.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('schedules', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('department_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('department_id')->references('id')->on('departments');
            $table->string('schedule_name');
            $table->date('schedule_start_date');
            $table->date('schedule_end_date');
            $table->date('schedule_actual_end_date');
            $table->time('schedule_travel_time');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Please check laravel official documentation also here which is saying

> [After](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#column-modifiers)

is using as column modifier.